# Setting sub-property of a Spring bean

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to set a Spring bean sub-property using dot notation?  For instance:

```
<bean name="rememberMe" class="com.mydomain.security.RememberMeManager">
    <property name="cookie.domain" value=".${webRoot}"/>
</bean>
```

Or do I need to also create an intermediary bean for the Cookie object stored in RememberMeManager.getCookie()?

My objective is to set cookies set by my site to ".mydomain.com" instead of "mydomain.com". I have a properties file with `webRoot=mydomain.com` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's PropertyPlaceholder will have no problem with replacing placeholders that are substrings of the property/value, such as `".${webRoot}"`, and [according to the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html), it will also fallback to the system properties if no property in the properties file is found.

Did you try this? Does it work or not?

Comment: Actually, my question was in regards to `name="cookie.domain"`, and if sub-properties were allowed. I had tried it, but it wasn't giving me the result I wanted, which is why I asked here. But since I asked, I figured out what I did wrong and discovered that it does work.

Comment: What do you mean by "sub-properties"? Are you asking about what you can do with Spring's placeholders (`${` and `}`), or what the cookie specification allows?

Comment: sorry to not be clear. By sub-properties, I mean that `domain` is a sub-property of `cookie`. I've only seen top-level bean properties used in spring config files: `name="beanPropertyName"`, but I haven't seen sub-properties used, like: `name="beanPropertyName.subBeanPropertyName"`. Basically, I'm unsure about using a period in the name.

Comment: I don't think that would work. Rather you would wire up `<property name="cookie">` with a `<bean>` of that class (hopefully it's an easy POJO), and then set the `<property name="domain">` to your desired value.